# Delete one slide from a Google Slide Presentation using Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-slides

I need to use Google Apps Script, not the API.

- I create an empty presentation
- It seems newly created presentations always contains an empty slide by default
- I insert a slide (taken from an other prez) into the presentation.

-> I'd like to delete this empty slide, so that the presentation contains only the slide I paste into it.

The code I have:

```
var presentation = SlidesApp.create("my new presentation"); // creates an empty slide in the prez
presentation.insertSlide(0,slides.pop()); // a slide from a deck of slides collected elsewhere
presentation.getSlides().pop(); // here trying to delete the empty slide, doesn't work: the slide remains in the presentation.
presentation.saveAndClose();
```

Comment: I elaborated on the problem description in the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [`remove`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#remove()) the `Slide`. `pop()` just removes it from the array and returns the last slide in the `Slide []`.

```
var lastSlide=presentation.getSlides().pop(); 
lastSlide.remove();
```

Comment: how can I delete the nth slide, not the last?

Comment: @user2988 You would use `.splice()`. Read Mozilla documentation.

Comment: Shoul be something like this?
var nthSlide=presentation.getSlides().splice(nth,1);
?????

Comment: @user298 Yes. Then you should `remove()` it. Also note that, slides are counted from 0(not 1). Also, splice() returns a array. You need to remove the single slide in that array.

Comment: Ok this worked for me:
 
`for (i=lastColumn;i>1;i--){
slides[i].remove();
}`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first slide, use the `shift()` method. The `shift()` method pulls the first element off of the given array and returns it.

```
  // Remove first blank slide
  const removeFirstSlide = newPresentationSlide.getSlides().shift()
  removeFirstSlide.remove()
```

But remember, to remove the first blank slide, you need more slides in your Presentation.